# How to test whether a char is NOT in a string? (java, junit)

Tags: java, string, junit, char

As title says, im having trouble with my junit tests passing for checking if a character is not in a string and how to check if an empty string doesnt have a character. here is the method i have:

```
     public static boolean isThere(String s, char value){
  for(int x = 0; x <= s.length(); x++){
   if(s.charAt(x) == value){
    return true;
   } else if(s.length() == 0){
    return false;
   }
  }
  return false;
```

And here is the junit test:

```
    public void testIsThere() {
  {
   String sVal  = "Jeff George";
   boolean hasA = StringMethods.isThere(sVal,'e');
   assertTrue(hasA);
   boolean hasE = StringMethods.isThere(sVal, 'o');
   assertTrue(hasE);
   boolean notIn = StringMethods.isThere(sVal,'b');
   assertTrue(notIn);
  }
  {
   String sVal  = "";
   boolean nothingIn = StringMethods.isThere(sVal,'a');
   assertFalse(nothingIn);
   boolean notIn = StringMethods.isThere(sVal,'b');
   assertFalse(notIn); 
  }
 }
```

Thank you very much, appreciated

Comment: a better name this isThere() would be containsChar()

Comment: Some better formatted code and a clearer explanation of what exactly it is that isn't working would help us help you.

Comment: I think you simply want to `assertFalse(notIn)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You are just duplicating functionality that already exists.

Comment: it should be assertFalse, you are correct, that is a typing error on my part, thank you

Comment: Some of the questions on SO these days make me want to cry :'(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `String.indexOf()` instead:

```
public static boolean contains(String s, char value){
    return s != null && s.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

String sVal = "Jeff George";
assertTrue(contains(sVal, 'e'));
sVal = null;
assertFalse(contains(sVal, 'e'));
```

Comment: this worked brilliantly, there is no way i could have seen that. return if s doesnt equal null AND that the index of the value is greater than -1, meaning that it is there and the string isnt empty. thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Why are you doing this? Your function is already implemented as a method on String. Use [String.indexOf](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) instead:

```
s.indexOf('a') == -1
```

I think Carl Manaster was right in the comments about your specific problem - you need to use `assertFalse` not `assertTrue` here:

```
String sVal  = "Jeff George";
boolean notIn = StringMethods.isThere(sVal, 'b');
assertFalse(notIn); // not assertTrue
```

As an aside, `notIn` is a terrible name for that variable - it means exactly the opposite of what it says. Maybe that is why you got confused.

Comment: it should be assertFalse, you are correct, that is a typing error on my part, thank you

Answer (score 2):

With Java 6 you can just do

```
final String s = "This is a test";
s.contains("x"); // False
s.contains("t"); // True
```

Comment: Two flaws: 1) It's actually Java 1.5. 2) It doesn't compile. It takes a `CharSequence`: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you encountering ?

Firstly,

```
  for(int x = 0; x <= s.length(); x++){
```

doesn't look right. `x` is going to run off the end of your string (`use x < s.length()` instead if you want to iterate through a string). But higher level functions are available for doing what you want (see the other answers here).

Answer (score 0):

If String.indexOf(char) returns -1, hasA is false. Otherwise, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Or, try StringUtils.contains() from apache commons - that will handle the null String case for you as well.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.String,%20char%29

Comment: apache commons is a poorly designed and implemented code cancer

Comment: Besides, using a 3rd party library for doing such elementary things, is, IMO, sheer madness. I mean, if you're going to stuff a jar in your app just to compare a String against `null` and do a `contains(...)` on it, I wonder how many 3rd party jars will be there when the app gets shipped! :)

Comment: +1 because a down-vote seems awful harsh.  Apache commons is a widely accepted and used library.  Is it way-overkill for just this one problem?  Certainly.  Has Java 1.5 and 1.6 made many of the functions in commons redundant?  Yup.  But sheesh...